# clear claims in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

i have the index

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ClaimsIdentity nd = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>{ new Claim("role","manager") });
            ClaimsPrincipal.Current.AddIdentity(nd);

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("user",true);

            return View();
        }
```

where i login and set some claims.

then i have a about where i signout.

```
public ActionResult About()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            return View();
        }
```

Afterwards i try to access the claim in the contact view.

```
public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            var firstclaims = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.FirstOrDefault();

            return View();
        }
```

And for some reason it is still there.I even cleaned out my cookies but still that claim is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem that you are mixing Forms Authentication and MembershipProvider with a new framework Asp.Net Identity. If you are using claims and Identity, then don't use `FormsAuthentication` methods and related.

If you need an example how this works, create a new project in Visual Studio 2013 with MVC and Individual Authentication and look through the code given in the template.